# How to make sure an HTTP request is performed even if the user quits the Activity

Tags: android, http, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am developing an App where I need to perform several HTML requests. There are certain POST requests which I need to make sure they are performed (e.g. the user inputs data that needs to be stored in the server). Normally, I would use an AsyncTask in the same Activity the user was interacting with, but this activity is closed right away after the user makes the input and the POST request may not have finished yet (due to a slow connection or whatever). In that case, the activity would be destroyed and (as far as I understand) the AsyncTask would not finish its job.

Which is the correct way to send data to the server independently of the activity's lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the job in an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), the Service will destroy itself when it is finished.

[Here is a relevant tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-background-services-with-intentservice/) on the matter (relevant code copied below).

The IntentService that will run your background code.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService(String name) {
        // Used to name the worker thread
        // Important only for debugging
        super(MyIntentService.class.getName());
        setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Invoked on the worker thread
        // Do some work in background without affecting the UI thread
    }
}
```

Register your IntentService in the manifest.

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.app.MyIntentService">
</service>
```

Call your IntentService whenever you need to run it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
// Put some data for use by the IntentService
intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this isn't explained clearly in the documentation and I couldn't find an answer like this here.